# How to represent model data in a collapsable list with asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.Net MVC and I'm trying to display some data from my models into a view. I am trying to accomplish what I've shown in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/4stxvmqh/2/

But with the Groups and Subgroups being data from my models.

Here are my models, controller and ViewModel.

**Subgroup Model**:

```
public class SubGroup
{
public int SubGroupId { get; set; }
public string SubGroupName { get; set; }
public Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

**Group Model**

```
public class Group:
{
public int GroupId { get; set; }
public string GroupName { get; set; }
public List<SubGroup> SubName { get; set; }
}
```

**CascadeViewModel:**

```
public class CascadeViewModel
{
public List<Group> Group { get; set; }
public List<SubGroup> SubGroup { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
  public ApplicationDbContext Subgroup = new ApplicationDbContext();
  public ApplicationDbContext Group = new ApplicationDbContext();
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
     var Categories = Group.groups.ToList();

     var cascadeView = new CascadeViewModel();

     var SubCategories = Subgroup.subgroups.ToList();

     cascadeView.Group = Categories;
     cascadeView.SubGroup = SubCategories;

     return View(cascadeView);
  }
```

So basically I'm trying to figure out how to set up my controller so I can represent the model data from my Subgroup model and my Group model in a cascading list appropriately. Most groups have the same subgroups but there are a few groups with only one or two subgroups. I'm trying to do this as efficiently and with as little code as possible. Please let me know the best route to take for this scenario. My ultimate goal is when a subgroup is clicked, it sends the subgroup name and its corresponding group name to a separate controller. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Subgroup Model:

```
public class SubGroup
{
    public int SubGroupId { get; set; }
    public string SubGroupName { get; set; }
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
}
```

Group Model:

```
public class Group
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public List<SubGroup> SubName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ApplicationDbContext Subgroup = new ApplicationDbContext();
public ApplicationDbContext Group = new ApplicationDbContext();
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Group> Categories = Group.group.GroupJoin(Subgroup.subgroup, x => x.GroupId, y => y.GroupID, (Group, SubGroup) => new { Group, SubGroup }).Tolist();
    return View(Categories);

}
```

View:

```
@model XXX.Group

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
     <div data-role="collapsible">
         <h4> @item.GroupName </h4>
         <ul data-role="listview">
            @foreach (var item2 in Model.SubName)
            {
                <li><a href="#">item2.SubGroupName </a></li>
            }
         </ul>
     </div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I did have one error in my controller code. The error CS1061 which states there's no ToList method for the anonymous function in the controller. Do you have any idea how to fix this? Thanks again.

Comment: you can try with Linq.
[This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx)
and you will edit view '@model List<XXX.Group>'